# Drag and Drop functionality inside canvas using HTML5

Tags: html

Hello all can we place drag and drop functionality inside canvas using html5??

My actual requirement is to drag the image into textbox that should be done inside the canvas...
please share your ideas..The following link i used to learn drag and drop but it should be done inside the canvas..

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

Comment: You should post your specific problem and sample code that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can learn more in this tutorial: http://html5.litten.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-an-html5-canvas/

From your limited description in your question, it sounds like you drag items over the canvas and this tutorial is likely the best match.

This is the actual code you can paste into file and open in HTML5 compliant browser and it will work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Drag and Drop Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>

<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas;
var ctx;
var x = 75;
var y = 50;
var WIDTH = 400;
var HEIGHT = 300;
var dragok = false;

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();
}

function clear() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() {
 clear();
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
 rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
 rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
}

function myMove(e){
 if (dragok){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
 }
}

function myDown(e){
 if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 +
 canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop &&
 e.pageY > y -15 + canvas.offsetTop){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  dragok = true;
  canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
 }
}

function myUp(){
 dragok = false;
 canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

init();
canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
canvas.onmouseup = myUp;

</script>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Mike  have a look on http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

Comment: follow the instructions in the article link I posted and you'll be able to.  there is also a working example near the end of the tutorial you can drag a black box around white canvas.

Comment: Thank you @Mark S.  But please go through the link i given to http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop it is not kinetic js to use its a simple javascript so could you able to tell how to implement the same feature in kineticJS